# Retrieve mongodb data using jsp and display in table

Tags: mongodb, jsp

```
<script>
 var c;
   var database = "torchdb";
   var ou;
  DBCursor cursor;
   try {
 MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient();
DB db = mongoClient.getDB(database);
DBCollection con = db.getCollection("torchReleaseUnit");
cursor = con.find();


 while(cursor.hasNext())
 {
    //out.println(cursor.next());
    ou +=cursor.next();
 }  
 out.println(ou);
 c =  JSON.parse(ou);
out.println(c);
out.println("middle");

}
 finally{
      cursor.close();
 }

</script>
```

I am trying to access data from mongoDB but can not access it. It seems that script tag does not executes.

---

I need to format like this

```
enter code here  try {
// read the json file
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray a = (JSONArray)jsonParser.parse(ss);    
      for (Object o : a)
      {
        JSONObject person = (JSONObject) o;
        Long  id = (Long) person.get("_id");
   %>

       <tr>
          <td><%out.println(id); %></td>
         <%String ip = (String) person.get("ip");%>
          <td><%out.println(ip); %></td>  
         <% String test_type = (String) person.get("test_type");%>
         <td><%out.println(test_type); %></td>
         <%   String os = (String) person.get("operating_system");%>
         <td><%out.println(os); %></td>
         <% String status = (String) person.get("status");%>
         <td><%out.println(status);%></td>
      </tr>
      <% 
         }%>
     </table>     
 <% }
```

finally{}
             %>

Comment: how are you executing the script?  Any error shown?

Comment: Unless I am mistaken you are trying to execute some Java code from within some Javascript tags. That is **not** going to work.

Comment: you are write when I removed script tag with <% %> it works , now I want to parse the JSON string so I can display in table.